# How to resize SVG in Inkscape from A1 to A0

Tags: svg, image-resizing, vector-graphics, inkscape

I am making a poster using Inkscape in SVG format. I have designed the poster in A1 but need to rescale it to A0 format. How can I perform the up-scaling?

Comment: [Related question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6574/in-inkscape-resize-both-the-document-and-its-content-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 33):

- Resize page to `A0` in the `File > Document properties` dialog.
- `Select all in all layers` in the `Edit` menu.
- `Transform` in the `Object` menu, select `scale` tab, and type 141.4 %, i.e. square root of 2 (note that the box `apply to each object separately` should not be ticked, while the box `scale proportionally` should).
- `Align` in the `Object` menu, select `With page` in the dropdown, tick the `Treat selection as group` box and then click the horizontal and vertical alignments.

If you are doing other resizes (from A4, A3, ... to any other A format), only the scaling changes in what is above. For a difference of 1 unit upwards in the A number, it will be 141.4 %, two units, 200%, three, 282.8%. When downsizing, e.g. A0 to A1, A3 to A4, (or any other one unit downsize), it will be 70.71%; two units, 50%, three units, 35.36%.